# Wrapper service in code-shared project with nativescript not working

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, nativescript

I tried to create a wrapper for my service `NotificacionService`, so I can use a "mobile version" whit the same import. But it seems to be not working.

This is my code:

**my app.module.tns.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    AutoGeneratedComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    HideActionBarDirective
  ],
  imports: [NativeScriptModule, AppRoutingModule],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: CustomStorageServiceService,
      useValue: MovilStorageServiceService
    },
    {
      provide: NotificacionesService,
      useValue: NotificacionesMovilService
    }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
})
```

**notificaciones-movil.services.ts**

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
export class NotificacionesMovilService {
  constructor() {
    console.log('NotificacionesMovilService')
  }

  alerta(title, message, okButtonText = "ok") {

    dialogs.alert({ title, message, okButtonText }).then(respuesta => {
      console.log("termino");
    });
  }

  error(title, message, okButtonText = "ok", cb = () => {}) {
    console.log('Estamos en error')
    dialogs.alert({ title, message, okButtonText }).then(respuesta => {
      cb();
    });
  }
}
```

**notificaciones.services.ts**

```
import swal from "sweetalert2";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
export class NotificacionesService {
  constructor() {}

  alerta(title, message, okButtonText = "ok") {

    swal.fire(title, message, 'warning')

  }

  error(title, message, okButtonText = "ok", cb = () => {}) {
    swal.fire(title, message, 'error').then( (Parametros)=>{
      cb()
    } )
  }
}
```

When I call this service I have the next error:

> ERROR TypeError: this._notificacionesService.error is not a function

But if I invert this order works:

```
{
      provide: NotificacionesMovilService,
      useValue: NotificacionesService  
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `{
      provide: NotificacionesService , 
      useValue: NotificacionesMovilService 
    }`
Provide the general service use the private implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Because Im not injecting a existenting service, I need to change property `useValue` for `useClass`

[Here the docs:](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-providers#aliased-class-providers)

> ## Aliased class providers
>
> Suppose an old component depends upon the
>   `OldLogger` class. `OldLogger` has the same interface as `NewLogger`, but
>   for some reason you can't update the old component to use it.
>
> When the old component logs a message with `OldLogge`r, you want the
>   singleton instance of `NewLogger` to handle it instead. In this case,
>   the dependency injector should inject that singleton instance when a
>   component asks for either the new or the old logger.`OldLogger` should
>   be an alias for `NewLogger`.
>
> If you try to alias `OldLogger` to `NewLogger` with `useClass`, you end up
>   with two different `NewLogger` instances in your app.
>
> ```
> [ NewLogger,   
>     // Not aliased! Creates two instances of `NewLogger`   
>     { provide: OldLogger, useClass: NewLogger}]
> ```
>
> To make sure
>   there is only one instance of `NewLogger`, alias`OldLogger` with the
>   `useExisting` option.
>
> ```
> [ NewLogger,   
>    // Alias OldLogger w/ reference to NewLogger   
> { provide: OldLogger, useExisting: NewLogger}]
> ```